# Adding \ prior to a $ in a linux command parameter

Tags: linux, oracle

I have a parameter which is a string containing a dollar sign that needs to be passed into one shell command and then passed on through to another.

eg.

```
prog_name.sh abc\$xyz
```

prog_name.sh contains a call to an oracle pro*C program:

```
proc_exe $1
```

The backslash is stripped out after the first call to prog_name.sh, so I need to put it back in in the proc_exe call so the `$` is preserved and `$xyz` is not evaluated. This allows `abc$xyz` to be passed in correctly as a string and used inside `proc_exe`.

Comment: So, hypothetically a string like `abc; dd if=/dev/null of=/path/to/your/db` would still pass?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your actual goal:

```
$ ./prog.sh 'abc\$xyz'    # receives: abc\$xyz

$ ./prog.sh "abc\$xyz"    # receives: abc$xyz
```

Comment: Double quotes doesn't change the behaviour in this case. Double quotes  are for variables that include spaces AND you want variable substitution performed. Single quotes are for when you want a string literal -- with spaces and NO variable substitution performed.

Comment: @Dunes Hmm, thinking it over some more, I'm not sure what the OP's final goal is. I'll just put both examples in. Thank.

Comment: What I meant was that you might as well do `'abc$xyz'` and not bother with trying to escape the dollar sign.

Answer (score 2):

This should normally work

```
prog_name.sh 'abc$xyz'
```

Note that you don't need to repeat the backslash, because the dollar sign is not on the commandline in `proc_exe $1` -- variables won't be expanded more than once, so to say

You would consider to quote the `$1` in case it contains whitespaces:

```
proc_exe "$1"
```

that way, the parameter text will arrive at `proc_exe` as a single parameter

Comment: would the downvoter care to explain why? No more quoting _is_ required. You'd need to use `eval program $1` to begin to need 'meta-quotation'

Answer (score 0):

Never do a

```
proc_exe $1
```

or any other variable without `""` around it without need.

Instead, use

```
proc_exe "$1"
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Strings passed to Bash usually don't need to worry about that...because they are automatically processed.

Example:
test.sh:
    #!/bin/bash

```
./test2.sh $1
```

test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "In Test 2 $1"
```

Example call:

> ./test.sh 123\$456 = "In Test 2 123$456"